# Have all links open in a new tab?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window)

When I follow a link in a question on any question/answer on S[OUF] it doesn't open in a new tab. I think it should. I'm not a big fan of having to use the back button and wait for a page to load all over again.

Why don't all links open in a new tab anyway?

Comment: Because generally when people click on links, they don't want to open a new page, they want to move to a new location.

Comment: What about links that are on the same site vs. an outside site?

Comment: Learn how to use a browser. I suggest SuperUser for your question.

Comment: similar question: [Make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window)

Comment: Ask a 3 button mouse for your birthday ;-)

Comment: In the very least this should be considered as a user option somewhere, methinks. I'd like it. Clearly some other people want this functionality too, and it is seen on many other sites. I think these days (as the internet and browsers have evolved with tabs etc) that an _external_ link usually opens a new tab.

Comment: This feature makes way too much sense to be popular here.  For those that want it and use chrome, install the tampermonkey extension and this script: http://pastebin.com/0rAKbHZu

Comment: I wrote my own script to open links in new tab and have putted it on stackapps. you could get it [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/7803/stackexchange-link-newtaber-open-links-from-questions-and-answers-in-new-tab "StackExchange link newtaber")

Answer (score 11):

> Have all links open in a new tab?

### *No!*

Comment: Came here to try to figure out the argument against having all [external] links open in new tab. I was "taught" years ago that it was a "best practice". I have since read many arguments against it, primarily, "let the user decide". After reading the answer posted by @timothy-carter it makes more sense and I'm ready to make the shift. A simple "No" doesn't contribute to the discussion so I down-voted it and was then informed by a pop-up that I ought to add a comment as to why. So, here I am. Anyway, the question was closed 10 years ago so I'm surprised I even could down vote it.

Answer (score 6):

While I typically open question in a new tab, I believe making this the default behavior would be unconventional, and remove the user's option to open things as they desire. Additionally, modern browsers/operating systems typically provide you with many mechanisms to achieve this goal. Personally, I'm a fan of the center/wheel click to open things in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that trick.

Answer (score 2):

You could right-click and use the context menu to open the link in a new tab.

Comment: Or middle-click. I think that works in most browsers (but not on most laptops).

Comment: @mmyers, on my laptop if I click both buttons at the same time it behaves the same as a middle click.

Comment: I'm a ctrl+click kinda guy, but each to their own.

Comment: Really? I don't think I've tried clicking both at once. I operate the touchpad with my forefinger while resting my thumb on the button, so clicking both at once is somewhat awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo... If you do this, it means that people who just want to browse around the site in one window can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Even when you forget to use some modifier key or middle-click to open a link in a new tab or window: most browsers allow you to click the back button using the same modifier key. That will then open the previous page in a new tab or window.

(Like in Safari and Firefox on OS X: Command-click a link to open that link in a new tab, or Command-click the Back button to open the previous page in a new tab. This also works for pages further down in the history, like the list shown in Safari when keeping the back button pressed for a second. In Safari and Firefox the new tab will not have any history though; one cannot go back any further from that new tab.)

(Hence: no, please do not open all links in a new tab...)