# jsFiddle links automatically append "_target=blank"

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window)

Just as an idiot-proof measure, it would be nice to have jsFiddle-type links open in external windows automatically so I don't lose answers because I forgot to press SHIFT :(

Comment: More general discussion on this issue: [make links posted by users open in a new window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2275), and [Have all links open in a new tab?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35677)

Comment: What browser are you using? In all browsers except for Opera, you should get a "Are you sure?" prompt when leaving the page after you've starting typing a post.

Comment: If this was going to happen.. wouldn't you want `target="_newtab"` instead?

Comment: I use Chrome.  I'm just impressed my question scored a -10 already. Course record?

Comment: Nah, there was an answer yesterday that got eight downvotes __and three delete votes__ in less than one hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is saved as you type, you won't lose anything.

I really wouldn't want SO links to open new browser windows for any reason, make a habit of clicking links with the middle button so they'll open in a new tab.

Comment: I have the habit to right click and select the first option (this caused problems when I moved to Opera because they have it on the second option)... I didn't last more than 3 months with Opera :(

Comment: Middle button? I have a left and a right button.