# Social media link on profile should open in a new tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page, user-interface

On clicking on any social media link, say Twitter, it opens in the same tab.

I think it would be better if it opens in a new tab.

> [image: profile page with social media links]

<sup>I mean the link is available here.</sup>

Comment: So ctrl-click it. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @nicael I have normally seen in all good website whenever you click on link which is for twitter or facebook it always open in new tab. That's why I thought it is would be good if S.E. have that.

Comment: SE doesn't like the behavior you're requesting.  The only place on the site that forces links to open in new windows/tabs (that I've found, anyway) is in Chat. There are [older](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35677/have-all-links-open-in-a-new-tab) questions requesting this behavior from other links on site and they get declined.

Comment: I middle click.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see the problem. This behavior is the same across all sites in the network. You can easily use your browser's shortcut to open in a new tab.

I find it very annoying that some websites open a new page for almost everything. I would like to keep it this way.

Comment: (Usually ctrl-click)

Comment: Or long-tap on mobile devices ;) @nicael

Comment: Yes that what I exactly mean if I change setting it will open everything on new page which is annoying and I have noticed most of website have social links which open on new so I was just suggesting

Comment: Then right click, open in a new tab. Or use `Ctrl+Click`.

Comment: Sure :) but I guess there are more computer users on SE, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing should open in a new tab automatically.  A user who wants to do that has the ability to do so; you shouldn't take the choice away from those who don't want this behavior.

A few things on SE (Community Bulletin links are the example I remember) used to open in a new tab.  That raised the question of why *those* links and not *others*?  The inconsistency confused people and, as I noted, there was no good reason for it.  I believe the only SE links that open in new tabs now are ads, and treating ads this way is common enough on the web that people probably aren't surprised by it.

If you want to say the difference is on-site versus off-site links (SE question uses the same tab, social-media link uses a new tab), then you *still* have a problem -- why the social-media links in the profile but not external links in the "about" text or in post bodies?

The principle of least astonishment calls for not doing this and *especially* not doing it inconsistently.  The vast majority of the web opens links in the current tab; it's why browsers *have* a right-click option (or control-click or long-tap) to do otherwise.  It's what people expect.  Don't mess with that.