# Can links in the answers be popped up

Tags: support, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window)

I was taught in my html programming class to pop up to a new window when you have a link in a list, especially a long one. I'm used to seeing this on many websites so I forget to manually pop a window into a new browser when I find something that may answer one of my questions.
Can the links in answers be allowed to pop up to a new browser window?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window
(and you might want to question some of the other things you were taught in that class...)

Comment: *I will cut you.*

Comment: Any examples of those many websites that do this?

Comment: my html class was in the 90s. I've been in it for a long time.

Comment: @Pollyanna: Not before I do!

Comment: I like the way google does this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd rather they didn't. If I want a new window open, I'll do it myself. Middle click or `shift+click` will do the job just fine.

I'm surprised students are still being taught to do this. Most people now consider it to be annoying behaviour.

Comment: So actually, this is the answer to the question. Yes, links are allowed to be opened in a new window. Just be sure to hold down the right key for the browser of your choice. :-) (In Safari on a Mac: Command-Click for new tab; Command-Option-Click for new window.)

Comment: Middle-click FTW!

Answer (score 10):

> I was taught in my html programming class to pop up to a new window when you have a link in a list

No offense buddy, but your html programming class sucks. The browser should not be presuming that I want to have a new window open up -- that choice should be left to me the viewer.