# Make links in "comment to author popup" work differently

Tags: feature-request, review, user-interface

When I select "Delete" in a Low Quality Review (or Recommend for Deletion, depending on the site). You get the pop-up where you can leave an automatically inserted comment to the author (see below).

What is nice is that you don't have to hit the actual circle to select a comment, you can click anywhere on the text (header and body). Except for the links (in blue), when you accidentally click an them you proceed to the page clicked, and you have to go back in the browser, select "Delete" once more and aim better for the selected reason you wanted to use for comment. This happens to me about once a day.

I know where these links lead to and I nowadays seldom if ever want to follow them. Can these links be made to function differently for the reviewer ( 
 **not** in the real text inserted as comment to the author), so you don't end up on a new page when you click on the link accidentally?

Possible solutions I could see (in order of diminishing convenience), but there might be others:

- some selection at the bottom of the pop-up where you have to enable the links in the pop-up
- a per site (or global) preference to disable the links in this pop-up.
- make the blue text only show some help balloon when hovering, explaining how to get to the page the author will be directed to in the comment itself
- always open the link in a new window/tab if clicked from the pop-up
- have a confirmation show up that asks if you really want to leave the review
- enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Left-click for selection in the pop-up (which would open a new window/tab if you hit a link)

[image]

Comment: In general, "make links pop up in a new window" is [not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window) a [popular](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37041/can-links-in-the-answers-be-popped-up) concept here.

Comment: @Catija I would prefer not to have to close an unwanted window/tab either, that is why it is not on the top of my list of possible  alternatives. But even that is better for the workflow while reviewing, than moving away from the page you are working on.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136270/can-the-links-be-disabled-in-the-vote-to-close-dialog but that's declined and for the vote to close dialog rather than low quality post dialog

Comment: The "enable Ctrl+Left-click for selection in the pop-up (which would open a new window/tab if you hit a link)" suggestion is nice; it seems like it would be the least intrusive and most smooth.

Comment: @JasonC: true, unless you are using a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the usefulness of this request. Clicking the text is a nice feature, but if you try to hit the radio button, it is almost impossible to mishit. And even if you do so, making it harder to hit the URL is worse in my opinion than the accidental mishit you do.

For people not that familiar with the close reasons (thousands of new users) the link are a must-read. For the few of 'us', the more experienced users, they are just 'knowledge'. So the benefit for the large group outweighs here in my opinion.

And since opening in a new window is declined over and over again, I don't think that option is going to make it (while it is the least bad option in my opinion).

Comment: I had not realised there are 42K+ potential reviewers total on [so], although I would not call them new users having earned 2K rep. I certainly don't want to make it more difficult on the new reviewers. What I don't understand is why you find a new window the least bad option, and prefer that over some switch to suppress these links hidden out of sight in your preferences (which experienced reviewers could switch on).

Comment: SE isn't really fond of a lot of toggles in the user profile.