# While writing a new question, open "Related Questions" in new page

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, related-questions

When you write your question a "Related Questions" list pops.

Sometimes I want to check if a question has a good answer, so I will not add duplicate question.

The thing is that the link opens the page in the same page (_self).

I think it will be better if it opened in new tab so I will be able to go back to my question.

Comment: Personally, I dislike sites that force me to open a new window because they take away your choice. You could just middle click on it.

Comment: As an aside: *I want to check if a question has a good answer*. Please check if *the question* is the same as well.

Comment: But, @JohnP, would *anyone* want to open this in the same window? That said, one should indeed never rely on this, so one should indeed learn how to force opening in a new window, to avoid having to type the question again. And for all we know, it might very well be on purpose in this specific use case. ;-)

Comment: @Arjan You're right that no one would (_probably_) want to open it in the same window and this _might_ be one of those rare use cases where it's useful :) _But_ the fix for this is so trivial that I don't really think force opening it in a new window is a better option.

Comment: In my comment above *"type the question again"* should read *"type the question's title again"*.

Comment: @Arjan: it is not only for typing the title again, as sometimes i find myself edit the question title after i wrote the question.

Comment: Ah, good point, @shani. (And kudos for then checking the questions too!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All browsers that I know of have a feature to open a link in a new window. For most, it's as simple as holding down a modifier key (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) while you left-click the link, or middle-clicking the link.
For others, you might have to right-click and select the appropriate option from a context menu.

But whatever the option is, you should learn it for your browser and use it each time you want to do this. The web designer should not force his/her choices on us. I, for one, don't want everything to open in a new tab/window.

Also see the answers to these two questions for more about the community's general feelings on using `target="_blank"` in links:

- [Make links posted by users open in a new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window)
- [By default make links target blank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91207/by-default-make-links-target-blank)

Comment: I know that, but i find that for myself in 100% of the cases that i want to check the question before i can decide not to post my own question so in this case i thought it will be better.

Comment: @shani: Then in 100% of cases, you can use the handy-dandy shortcut provided by your browser. In general, I oppose forcing choices like this on the user. There's no easy mechanism to right-click and open the link in the *same* window.

Comment: @Cody Gray:What you are saying is that developers should never use the  target=”_blank ,_new... and we can actually remove those options from HTML code.

Comment: @shani: Hmm, I wasn't really saying that, but I suppose I *could* say that. I don't disagree with it. But making blanket statements like that isn't really my style. And there's no way such things will ever be removed; there's zero benefit but the expense of breaking existing implementations.

Comment: @shani I think the defining characteristic here is that the fix is so tiny (middle click or shift click), that we don't really need to do anything.

Comment: @shani Cody Didn't say that but I would go that far. Only when a link advertises that it opens up in a seperate window and only when there is the option ,i.e. two links then I like it

Comment: Ok i gave up as i see that most of you don't agree, so I will accept your answer Cody Gray.

Comment: @shani, I agree entirely. I have wasted a lot of time because the link opened in the same window. This is the first I time I have seen the keyboard solution. I would prefer a little popup menu choice.