# Where should I ask this question which is possibly Programmers.SE/Webmasters.SE related?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

> I heard someone say that I should never open links in new windows or tabs, because this will confuse the end-user. I've seen my mother do this several times - she tries to click the back button (even though it's greyed out). In many cases this results in leaving the website.
>
> I am not sure if I should open pages in new windows or tabs or in the current page. They both have their own advantages.
>
> My website is for a hosting company, so probably, many developers will visit the website. So what should I do? Err on the side of caution?

Where should I ask this question? I was thinking about Programmers.SE or Webmasters.SE but I'm not sure.

Comment: Not [Programmers.se]. I'm sure that it's been asked before either on [ux.se] or [webmasters.se]

Comment: @ChrisF UX, that's a good one.

Comment: And as for the answer, I present [Make links posted by users open in a new window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2340)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Great, thanks :)